# redirect to controller action from view component

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, razor

Trying to return a regular view or even redirect to a controller action method from a viewcomponent(.cs) for one edge case.  Is this possible?

Answer (score -2):

```
@Html.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName", param)
```

In the controller return a partial view:

```
    public ActionResult MethodName(paramType param)
    {
        return PartialView("viewName", param);
    }
```

Comment: This does not work from within a ViewComponent, thank you though